# Not triggering React event correctly

Tags: javascript, flux, refluxjs

I have a Reflux store which seems to cause an error when triggering an action:

```
var taskStore = Reflux.createStore({
  listenables: [taskActions],
  init: function(){
    this.tasks = [];
    this.index = {};
    this.trigger(this.tasks);
  },
  onLoad: function(arr){
    var idx = {}
    arr.forEach(function(ele){
      idx[ele.id] = ele
    });
    this.tasks = arr;
    this.index = idx;
    this.trigger(arr);
  }
});
```

When the action `load` is called and the `onLoad` method triggers, it fails on the `this.trigger` method with Chrome saying the error is **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined**

The call stack eventually gets me to the Reflux listen method:

```
listen: function(callback, bindContext) {
    bindContext = bindContext || this;
    var eventHandler = function(args) {
        callback.apply(bindContext, args);
    }, me = this;
    this.emitter.addListener(this.eventLabel, eventHandler);
    return function() {
        me.emitter.removeListener(me.eventLabel, eventHandler);
    };
},
```

It's the callback in callback.apply, but it looks like that callback is undefined for some reason .

I'm clearly doing something wrong to trigger such a deep error, but I don't know what. Can someone tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong in my store?

The code that calls the store calls it like this:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    mixins: [
        Reflux.connect(taskStore,"tasks"),
        Reflux.connect(taskIndex, "index"),
    ],
...
```

Comment: What does the code that calls `listen` look like?  I'm willing to bet you're not passing in a callback...

I got this error [here](https://github.com/danesparza/GetTheFluxGist/blob/master/js/components/GistApp.react.js#L30) when I forgot to pass in `this._onChange`

Comment: The code that calls listen uses the Reflux.connect mixin. I've added it to the question.

Comment: This might be a bug, so I made a quick note on it at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs/issues/219). If you have any other information such as version of reflux and react that you're using, please let me know there.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem. In my case it was my fault when declaring the component:

```
global.FilmList = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.connect(filmListStore, "list")],
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.listenTo(filmListStore, this.eventChange);
    },
    render: function() {
```

I had set both mixins and this.listenTo() method. I've removed the this.listenTo() and this solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Just spent an hour trying to solve this issue myself.

In my case, the method i told Reflux.ListenTo to trigger, didn't exist.

So i had

```
Reflux.listenTo('FooStore', 'onUserDeleted')
```

and i didnt have onUserDeleted: function() { } in the store.